# Sqlite Transaction, inserts only last insert

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

When ever i insert an order with more than one items in the order details, only the last oder details item get inserted.

Am inserting into a database using the following code

```
Try
    order_id = value.ID
    If order_id = 0 Then
        cmd = New SQLiteCommand(insert_order, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", value.CustomerID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", value.Status)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deliver", value.Deliver)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created", Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deleted", "0")
        order_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Else
        cmd = New SQLiteCommand(update_order, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", value.CustomerID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", value.Status)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deliver", value.Deliver)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created", Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deleted", "0")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", order_id)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        '// delete previous order details
        cmd = New SQLiteCommand(delete_order_details, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", order_id)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

    '// Add order details
    For Each itm As typOrderDetail In value.orderDetails
        cmd = New SQLiteCommand(insert_order_details, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cloth_id", itm.ClothID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_id", order_id)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", itm.Color)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", itm.Desc)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", itm.Qty)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", itm.Cost)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@service_id", itm.ServiceID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deleted", "0")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    sqlTrans.Commit()
    'If bSave Then sqlTrans.Commit() Else sqlTrans.Rollback()
Catch ex As Exception
    'sqlTrans.Rollback()
    Throw
Finally

    cmd.Dispose()
    conn.Dispose()
End Try
```

and here are the sql string

> INSERT INTO orders
>   ([customer_id],[status],[deliver],[created],[deleted]) VALUES
>   (@customer_id,@status,@deliver,@created,@deleted);select
>   last_insert_rowid();
>
> INSERT INTO orders_details
>   ([order_id],[service_id],[cloth_id],[desc],[deleted],[qty],[color],[cost])
>   VALUES
>   (@order_id,@service_id,@cloth_id,@desc,@deleted,@qty,@color,@cost)

Pls waht am i doing wrong?

Comment: i found out that it seems if the order_item did not change and i used the update command in sqlite, this issue happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see how you handle transactions in your code. Try this (in C#, sorry):

```
using(SqliteTransaction tr = con.BeginTransaction()){
   foreach(var itm in value.orderDetails) {
      //construct the command, add parameters, etc.
      ...
      //link the command to the transaction
      cmd.Transaction = tr;
      //execute the command
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   tr.Commit();
}
```

Comment: does this applies to the whole code i posted or just the order_details, anyway i tried it but its still the same

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure this will fix it, but keep the same SQLiteCommand object for all of the order details. Declare it outside of the loop, and just update parameter values and run the query in the loop.